# How to enable folder creation and Powerpoint creation in SharePoint 2013 document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have installed SharePoint 2013 and updated it with service pack1

and my SharePoint has all the latest updates,

in my SharePoint document library I don't see any option for creating new folder

when I click on add button it just open a browse option to upload files

I want to enable folder creation and PowerPoint creating when creating new item

in document library, what feature should I enable or what hot fixes should I apply

Answer (score 0):

To create a folder, simply click the New Folder button in the Files tab on the ribbon.

To enable Powerpoint files, you need to go to the ribbon and click on the Library tab and click on Library Settings. Click on Advanced Settings and set Allow Management of Content Types to Yes and click OK. You will get thrown back to the settings page where you can add a content type for Powerpoint.

The other option is to click the cog and Add an App. Select document library and click on the advanced settings link. In the dropdown select Powerpoint presentation as the default content type.

Comment: I have enabled what you said but it is not working